# cannot import sql file in phpmyadmin in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

**

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
>   the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

**

Hi, I'm having error in phpmyadmin in xampp. I exported database file ( filename.sql ) from phpmyadmin from Windows. But, I can't import this database file to phpmyadmin of Mac. It says this error. My project is done with Windows PC and I want to migrate into Mac.I tried with other Windows PC and it works well. But, I can't even import database file in Mac. I also tired with other formats like CSV etc. The same error happened. Anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you experience this bug:
https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4153/

which has been fixed in version 4.1.0-rc1.